# Error while creating a docker-machine SSH error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded

Tags: docker, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I am trying to create docker machine with a virtual machine using oracle virtualbox and ubuntu server 16.04 on windows 10 pro with the following command:

`$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox manager2`

but process ends with this error:

```
Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"
```

while VT-X is enabled (I have an intel cpu)

Answer (score 1):

This helped me out to solve the same error:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory=4096 --virtualbox-cpu-count=4 --virtualbox-disk-size=40960 --virtualbox-no-vtx-check default
```